# Qprogressbar stop sliding

Tags: python, pyqt

for an application in Python  I am working on, I need to show  a sliding progressBar with QT 4.7 , I can do it,but it is sliding only as far a QmessageBox is visible,it is very ennoing,I tried in many different ways to keep it sliding without messageBox without any success,I did not find anything about it on internet;this is my code for showing the bar:

```
    d=QtGui.QMainWindow()
    screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    size =  self.progressBar.geometry()
    self.progressBar.move((screen.width()/2)-size.width()/2,(screen.height()/2)-size.height()-100)
    self.progressBar.show()
```

To make it moving I have to add this:

```
        d=QtGui.QMainWindow()
        infoString="sto creando mmasgisDB!"
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(d,"Info", infoString)
```

As soon I click on the OK button the bar gets frozen. So I think there is something that I do not know related with QMainWindow, I need the help of someone more expert.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a `QMessageBox` and assign it to a variable like you did for main window. And then `QMessageBox.setInformation()` to set the string you want. Afterwards you may try `QMessageBox.execute()`.

Also you may try to `activate()` and `show()` mechanisms for QMessageBox. I hope it works the same for PyQT.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your widgets to display correctly within another widget, you must add them to a layout:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class windowSlider(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(windowSlider, self).__init__(parent)

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)

        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setValue(24)

        self.horizontalSlider = QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalSlider)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = windowSlider()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```